Followup question to "Invariant symbol, group representation"
There is a 2 year old answer by Cosmas Zachos which is very helpful regarding invariant symbols here.
Aside this context, I have never encountered these and thus I have 3 questions:

Why is it sufficient that this holds infinitesimaly? Surely what we really want is to show that $U_{\hspace{2mm}j}^{ l}\delta^{ j}_k U^{\dagger k}_{\hspace{2mm}i} = \delta^l_i$ for a gauge transformation $U$ (which surely holds also).

Do this invariant symbols imply a singlet representation because you can then use them to contract an object in $R$ with an object in $\bar{R}$ and have the guarantee that their contraction transforms like a singlet e.g.: $$\bar{\psi}^i\psi_i =\bar{\psi}^i\delta^j_i\psi_j\rightarrow \bar{\psi}^iU^\dagger U\delta U^\dagger U\psi =\bar{\psi}
^i\psi_i$$ I.e. showing the existence of the invariant symbol means you can contract objects which then means they are invariant. I mean this in the more general case, like for example with how a levi cevita is also an invariant symbol which then guarantees a singlet representation of $3\times 3\times 3$ ( 3 = fundamental rep of $SU(3)$) because we can contract 3 $\psi$.

I also see that if all the generators are found to be $0$ for a representation, then it is the trivial. However, I am not sure I follow that the book actually shows that so much as they just happen to cancel. I guess it's just saying we expected $x \rightarrow x+ \theta^aT^a $ because its to linear level in $\theta$ but we found $x\rightarrow x$ and so $T^a = 0 $ ?


